# In ruby how to use class level local variable? (a ruby newbie's question)

Tags: ruby

So suppose I have this (not working):

```
class User
   description = "I am User class variable"
   def print
       puts description
   end
end
```

So, how should I use the var description, how to pass this into a method as a default parameter, or used in the method directly? Thanks..

Answer (score 6):

In your case, the `description` is only local variable. You can change this scope using special characters `@`, `@@`, `$`:

```
a = 5
defined? a
=> "local-variable"

@a = 5
defined? @a
=> "instance-variable"

@@a = 5
defined? @@a
=> "class variable"

$a = 5
defined? $a
=> "global-variable"
```

For your purpose, I think it might be using by this way

```
class User
  def initialize(description)
    @description = description
  end

  def print
      puts @description
  end
end

obj = User.new("I am User")
obj.print
# => I am User
```

Comment: It's good that you showed `defined? a`, but he asked how to use a local variable .. and if you use @ or @@ or $  then your own answer suggests it's not a local variable. Therefore it's not answering the question. The great info you provide in your answer suggests that local variables are not local to the class.

Answer (score 5):

You can access the class-scope using `define_method`.

```
class User
   description = "I am User class variable"
   define_method :print do
       puts description
   end
end
```

> > User.new.print
>   I am User class variable
>   => nil

I don't think it's good idea, though :)

Answer (score 1):

To define a class variable, use an `@@`:

```
class User
   @@description = "I am a User class variable"

   def print
       puts @@description
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Instance variables must be prefixed with an **@** and are not accessible from outside.
Class variables must be prefixed with an **@@**.

The first time you use this variable anywhere in code, it will be initialized.
If you want to access the value from outside:

```
attr_reader :description
```

http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/tutorial.html

Comment: `attr_reader` works only for instance variables, not class variables. If you are using Rails, you can use `cattr_reader` to do this.

Comment: but I saw a code example use a variable like I did, so is it legal?

Comment: @user875883 That would be a strange code example. Maybe it was about showing how a local variable defined on the class level is NOT in scope inside the methods.